# SSL requirement for PayPal Express

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm using paypal-express `https://github.com/nov/paypal-express` gem for PayPal Express payments.

I send only information about item - title, price, quantity, currency to paypal to checkout in paypal site. Later I get response to my site about successful or not payment. Should I need SSL(https) to establish that?

Now it works on sandbox, but it fails for real payments:

```
PayPal API Error: 'Security error'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your error has anything to do with SSL. It's your PayPal credentials that are not correct.

To make a real payment, not Sandbox, you will need make sure this code is *not* being executed in your initializer:

```
Paypal.sandbox!
```

And you will need to be using an [API Signature for a live PayPal account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/#creating-an-api-signature). Remember, you can't make a live payment with a Sandbox account, and you can't make a Sandbox payment with a live account's API signature.

I have put together an example app that uses this gem, that you might find useful. It's in a [public repo on github](https://github.com/rlarcombe/paypal-mobile-checkout).